# Increment Alphabet characters to next character using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, char, conditional-statements, auto-increment

I am beginner in script programming and I would like to write a script in order to have an automatic ID (date+Uppercase characters).

The script is OK without the function IF. However, I still get some issues with my script. I don't succeed to increment the character with the condition of function IF.

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {

//Déclaration des variables
var SheetResponse = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var DerniereLigne =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastRow();
var DateToday = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'ddMMYY');

//Intégration du suffixe alphabétqiue pour l'ID
// If cells value (A.n)=(A.n-1) then character of cells "N.n" is incremented until "Z" (with n is number of LastRow)
if (SheetResponse.getRange(DerniereLigne,2).getValue() == SheetResponse.getRange(DerniereLigne-1,2).getValue()) {
        var AlphaNumber = SheetResponse.getRange(DerniereLigne-1,15).getValue().charCodeAt(0);
        var NextCode = AlphaNumber + 1;
        // Si Code (Z) alors restart to "A"
        if (NextCode > 90) {nextCode = 65;}
        var NextAlpha = String.fromCharCode( NextCode );
        }
// If not cells (N.n) is set to "A"
else {NextAlpha = "A";}

//Création de l'ID dans la derniére ligne et colonne "N"
SheetResponse.getRange(DerniereLigne,14).setValue(DateToday + NextAlpha);
SheetResponse.getRange(DerniereLigne,15).setValue(NextAlpha);

}
```

Please, Could someone help me.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: In this line: `if (NextCode > 90) {nextCode = 65;}`  The second variable `nextCode` does not have a capital letter `n`.

Comment: If you want to incremented until "Z", then check for `NextCode > 89` not `NextCode > 90`.  "Z" is 90, so 90 is greater than 89.

Comment: Dear @Sandy Good, thank you for your response. However I still get issue with the IF condition. The script for character incremntation was OK without the function IF. According to you, the IF statement is OK?

Comment: See updated answer at bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of a function that loops through all the capital letters of the alphabet, and then increments by one character:

```
function incrementAlpha() {
  var stringOfLetters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  var thisLoopAlpha = "",
      AlphaNumber = 1,
      NextCode = 0,
      NextAlpha = 0,
      thisCode = 0;

  for (var i=0;i<stringOfLetters.length;i+=1) {
    thisLoopAlpha = stringOfLetters[i];
    thisCode = thisLoopAlpha.charCodeAt(0);
    NextCode = thisCode + 1;
    // if Code (Z) then restart at "A"
    if (thisCode > 89) {
      NextCode = 65;
      NextAlpha = String.fromCharCode( NextCode );
    } else {
      //NextAlpha = "A";
      NextAlpha = String.fromCharCode( NextCode );
    };

    Logger.log('thisCode: ' + thisCode);
    Logger.log('NextCode: ' + NextCode);
    Logger.log('NextAlpha: ' + NextAlpha + "\n");
  };
};
```

I think that your code should be structured like this:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {

  //Déclaration des variables
  var SheetResponse = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var DerniereLigne =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastRow();
  var DateToday = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), 'ddMMYY');

  //Intégration du suffixe alphabétqiue pour l'ID
  // If cells value (A.n)=(A.n-1) then character of cells "N.n" is incremented until "Z" (with n is number of LastRow)
  if (SheetResponse.getRange(DerniereLigne,2).getValue() == SheetResponse.getRange(DerniereLigne-1,2).getValue()) {
    var AlphaNumber = SheetResponse.getRange(DerniereLigne-1,15).getValue().charCodeAt(0);
    var NextCode = AlphaNumber + 1;

    // Si Code (Z) alors restart to "A"
    if (NextCode > 89) {
      nextCode = 65;
      var NextAlpha = String.fromCharCode( NextCode );
    } else {
      // If not cells (N.n) is set to "A"
      NextAlpha = "A";
    }; 
  }
  //Création de l'ID dans la derniére ligne et colonne "N"
  SheetResponse.getRange(DerniereLigne,14).setValue(DateToday + NextAlpha);
  SheetResponse.getRange(DerniereLigne,15).setValue(NextAlpha);
}
```

Comment: Dear @Sandy Good, thank you for your answer for character incrementation.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Hello Sandy, the script you proposed does not work. My initial script was OK without IF. The IF statement seems not good. Basically, I Have tested the condition if(1 ==1), and the script function properly ("A" --> "B" --> "C" --> .... --> "Z" --> "A" --> ...). The issue is that my IF condititon does not work.

Comment: Try using triple equal signs instead of double equal signs.  Also, for debugging purposes, assign `SheetResponse.getRange(DerniereLigne,2).getValue()` to a variable, and check what the value is.  The only person who can determine what the value of `SheetResponse.getRange(DerniereLigne,2).getValue()`  without the spreadsheet is **you**.  Without the values, no one here can debug your code.  We can't magically know what the values are. Add, `Logger.log()` statements, then VIEW, the LOG.

Comment: Dear Sandy, I hav found asolution. When I put a String() in the IF condition, `if (String(LastCell) == String(PrevCell))`, the IF statement works good. Thank you for your support

Comment: Awesome. Glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function that returns the next string in lexicographic order:
'A' -> 'B' -> ... 'Z' -> 'AA' -> 'AB' -> 'AC' -> ... 'AZ' -> 'BA' -> 'BB' -> ... 'ZZ' -> 'AAA' etc.

```
function nextString(str) {
    if (! str)
        return 'A'  // return 'A' if str is empty or null

    let tail = ''
    let i = str.length -1
    let char = str[i]
    // find the index of the first character from the right that is not a 'Z'
    while (char === 'Z' && i > 0) {
        i--
        char = str[i]
        tail = 'A' + tail   // tail contains a string of 'A'
    }
    if (char === 'Z')   // the string was made only of 'Z'
        return 'AA' + tail
    // increment the character that was not a 'Z'
    return str.slice(0, i) + String.fromCharCode(char.charCodeAt(0) + 1) + tail
```

}